# How we can hear sound of an explosion before the shockwave?

Tags: acoustics, shock-waves

I noticed in couple of videos of big explosions muffled sound right after the explosion flashes but before the shockwave. What is this sound?

Here are some examples from the net:

- https://youtu.be/rInxeNBXS3o
- https://youtu.be/_BgJEXQkjNQ?t=74
- https://youtu.be/lwNS7sGW77k
- https://youtu.be/PgLzgdbfeJE?t=16

Comment: I think it would be at least interesting to look at how the sound for those videos originated: in particular how well it was synced with the video an whether it was dubbed, which it may have been for some of them.

Comment: I agree but I doubt that this is some video to sound synchronization effect.

Comment: In the first at least the initial thump is the detonation cord: you can see the flash in a couple of frames at the bottom of the picture.  I have no trust in the sound of the second at all.  Have not looked further, sorry.

Comment: I agree with @tfb, you should not hear anything due to the explosion before the shock wave (unless some small projectile ejected during the explosion propagated ahead of the main shock, which would produce its own "little" shock).  The _piston_ (i.e., heated and compressed air in explosions) travels faster than sound, thus sound waves should not out-run it.  If you hear something before the shock, it came from something else...

Comment: Ok, I  am removing the second link because it is unreliable indeed  and putting the recent SpaceX explosion on its place, where is the detonation cord in this video?

Comment: The sounds you hear in the SpaceX video are from previous explosions that occurred before the current visual one, so no problem there.  The 3rd and 4th had no sounds prior to shock arriving.  The only thing, and this is a stretch, that might be happening if the camera is sensitive enough is a sound wave in the ground for the 4th video.  However, I would need to know more about the audio-video synchronization etc. before saying much more.

Comment: The sound in SpaceX video matches the flashes of big the explosion, so I don't think that this is from previous explosions. In the 3rd and 4th, they have the sound that I'm talking about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pressure wave can travel through solids at a greater speed than through air. And this means a "pre sound" can reach you before the shock wave does - as the motion of the ground will in turn induce a sound wave in the adjacent air.

Comment: Yes, this matches with the research and observations I made. I came to the conclusion that this sound is from the P-wave of the earthquake made by a big explosion which travels approximately 2 to 8 km/s in the Earth's crust and can be heard only in big enough explosions.

Comment: I thought this as well, but my initial assumption was that the amplitude would be too small for the speaker to respond but perhaps I was wrong.

Comment: The amplitude depends from the size of the explosion, that's why you can't hear it from a small explosion because the amplitude/energy propagated through the earth is too small.

Answer (score 0):

Technically a shockwave is a propagating disturbance that travels *faster* than   soundwaves in a particular medium. If the wave travels slower than sound it isn't a shockwave. The answer to your question though is that the energy and displacement of pressure that are the "shockwave" you're probably thinking of, propagate through air at a slow speed than sound waves do.

Comment: No, I know what a shockwave is, and it is clearly visible where it is and how it is propagating from most of the videos. This sound I hear is before the shockwave.